# Safe to remove unused ASP.NET membership tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I'm going to be using the ASP.NET Membership model on my website. However, there are multiple tables that I do not plan to ever use, such as:
aspnet*Paths
aspnet*PersonalizationAllUsers
aspnet*PersonalizationPerUser
aspnet*Profile
aspnet*WebEvent*Events

Is it safe to delete these tables or will I cause problems with the way ASP.NET's membership framework works (in System.Web.Security) ?

I really like keeping things clean and these tables are bothering me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) and choose which parts you want to remove:

```
-R all|m|r|p|c|w
```

> all - All services, including common
>   tables and stored procedures shared by
>   the services
>
> m - Membership
>
> r - Role Manager
>
> p - Profile
>
> c - Web Parts Personalization
>
> w - Web Events

In the future, run the tool with the `-A mr` parameter to only add the membership and role manager.

Comment: Keep in mind that aspnet_regsql.exe will only allow you to uninstall features if the tables are empty. You'll need to clear out the tables before running the tool as Davy suggested.